# What did Jack Sparrow mean when he said "Clearly you've never been to Singapore"

Tags: dialogue, pirates-of-the-caribbean, curse-of-the-black-pearl

After cutting Elizabeth's corset off in *Pirates of the Caribbean*, the guard comments "never would have thought of that." And Jack turns to him and delivers the line in question: "You've clearly never been to Singapore." What does he mean with that?

PS: this question was asked [here](http://www.quora.com/What-did-Jack-Sparrow-mean-when-he-said-Clearly-youve-never-been-to-Singapore-in-Pirates-of-the-Caribbean) but I don't agree with the implication that was being get at there.

Comment: Err, which particular implication do you not agree with, there are several unrelated suggestions.

Comment: Regardless, Jack was referencing a name that would not be given to the country until nearly 100 years later. In roughly 1730 (when PoC takes place), it was known as Temasek. It was not named Singapore (meaning Lion City in Malay) until 1819.

Comment: @user51419 [Not true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_Singapore#Early_European_names) - Singapore was first called that some time in the 14th century. It was known to Westerners by a number of names in the 1700s, but "Singapore" was among them (along with "Sinagpura" and various other variants).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Singapore, at that time, was one of the busiest ports in Asia.  If not *the* busiest port.  Pirates would have visited Singapore often.  Also, prostitution is not illegal in Singapore.  A prostitute wears something which makes them alluring, and a corset definitely fits that bill.

The inference is that Jack Sparrow had frequently been to Singapore, had experience with prostitutes and knew how to disrobe them.

Comment: As mentioned in above, Singapore is named as such way after movie's time period. So how could he call the country as singapore if it hasn't named as such yet?

Comment: And more importantly, he has enough experience with corsets to know they can severely restrict breathing.

Comment: Use of the name "Singapore" is a screen writing error, or possibly just using the name that would be familiar to the audience rather than the one that would be correct.

Comment: Not an error, definitely for its intended audience, as is the movie overall, and they wouldn't know historic Singapore from their left elbow, so the modern 'version' of Singapore is referred to, one the audience, from at least the last 80 odd years its been a saucy port of call would instantly recognize. Speak to an old sailor or soldier that got posted or visited there, they'd know, speak to a modern tourist, or local, they'd know too but might not admit it. Also watch 'Stand up, virgin solders' and 'Saint jack' for reference, etc